# Is there a global way to catch all EditText focus changes in Android?

Tags: java, android, lost-focus

Is there a clever way to avoid repeating the first block of code below a dozen times? The second block is identical in form to the first and I have several more that will have the same form. I'm thinking about an array of `EditText` fields (good idea? bad [why?]?) but is there a **global** way to make **one block** catch **all changes in focus**?

```
   txtExclude.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
       public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) 
       {
           if (!hasFocus)
               if (txtExclude.getText().length() == 0)
                   txtExclude.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

       }});

   txtRequired.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
       public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) 
       {
           if (!hasFocus)
               if(txtRequired.getText().length() == 0)
                   txtRequired.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
       }});
```

*EDIT*

Non-working implementation of first Answer:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnFocusChangeListener
{
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // call superclass's version
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // inflate the GUI

      final EditText txtPattern = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPattern);

       final EditText txtLegal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLegal);

       final EditText txtExclude = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtExclude);

       final EditText txtRequired = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtRequired);

       EditText txtLetters = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtLetters);

   } // end method onCreate

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        return; // breakpoint here **********************
    }
} // end class MainActivity
```

No matter which `EditText` gained or lost focus during debug, breakpoint was not reached.

Comment: try android:focusableInTouchMode   and  
android:focusable  properties in parent layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an other way.

Make a CustomEditext class in your package by subclassing the EditText like below

*Let your package is `com.android.app`*

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText {

public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction,
        Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {

    if (!focused)
        if (getText().length() == 0)
            setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
}
}
```

you can use this customEditText in your layout like below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.android.app.CustomEditText
    android:id="@+id/com.example.customedittext1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >
</com.android.app.CustomEditText>

<com.android.app.CustomEditText
    android:id="@+id/edEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >
</com.android.app.CustomEditText>

<com.android.app.CustomEditText
    android:id="@+id/edContact"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Contact"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >
</com.android.app.CustomEditText>
```

You will not need to set onFocusChangedListner() on every Edit Field.

Hope this helps

Comment: @Qadir--THANK YOU. This did it for me. Sorry it took WEEKS to get back to it and decide that it was worth taxing my brain. I'll share in my Answer how I made it work if any part of it seems to be different from your Answer.

Answer (score 11):

1. You can use ViewTreeObserver and add the onGlobalFocusChange listener on your root view layout. Below is the sample code :

(Putting a line with 8 blank spaces here will format first line(s) of code.)

```
    findViewById(R.id.yourRootContainer).getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalFocusChangeListener
    (
       new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalFocusChangeListener() 
       {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalFocusChanged(View oldFocus, View newFocus) 
            {
                whatever();
            }
       }
    );
```

2. You can use custom focus listener, differentiate using views id. Below is sample code :

   ```
   private class MyFocusChangeListener implements 
   View.OnFocusChangeListener 
   {
       @Override
       public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) 
       {
           if (view.getId() == R.id.my_view_id) 
           {
               doSomethingHere();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

And use it as :

```
myView1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new MyFocusChangeListener());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you like to handle all changes in focus, you might want to implement OnFocusChangeListener

Something like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnFocusChangeListener
{

    @Overrride
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
    {
     //check which view changed and do some stuff
    }

}
```

Comment: --please see EDIT to OQ.

Comment: I can't check the code at the moment but you might want to try and add TextChangedListener to your EditText.

Answer (score 1):

@Qadir Hussain had my problem's solution WEEKS ago (time flies). Here's how I implemented it in `activity_main.xml`, with an additional tweak:

```
<com.dslomer64.wordyhelperton.CustomEditText
    android:id="@+id/txtRequired"
     ...        
    android:hint="@string/required_hint"
    >
    <requestFocus />
</com.dslomer64.wordyhelperton.CustomEditText>
```

And in `MainActivity.java`:

```
static CustomEditText txtExclude;
static CustomEditText txtRequired;
...
...onCreate...

  txtExclude   = (CustomEditText) findViewById(R.id.txtExclude);
  txtRequired  = (CustomEditText) findViewById(R.id.txtRequired);
```

And in `CustomEditText.java`:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class CustomEditText extends EditText
{
  public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
  {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect)
  {
    super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
    if (getText().length() == 0) setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    else                         setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
  }

  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
  {
    super.onTextChanged(s, start, before, count);
    if (getText().length() == 0) setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    else                         setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Listen to all the focus changes for the views in the activity's window.

```
window.decorView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalFocusChangeListener { oldFocus, newFocus ->
    println("old=$oldFocus new=$newFocus")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - although code/config snippets might provide some limited short-term help, a proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.